# Translating "at least" in an inequality problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:

> Li Qiang is listening to a symphony that has 2 movements. The first movement has 3 beats per measure and the second movement has 4 beats per measure. The symphony has 446 measures. In an attempt to count the beats, Li Qiang counts at least *x* of the beats in the first movement and exactly *b* beats in the second movement. Let *x* be the number of beats in the first movement and *b* be the number of beats in the second movement. Which of the following inequalities must be true?

So he counts at least *x* beats in measure one and then every 3 beats I get one measure, so I can assume this:

$$\frac{x}{3}\geq a$$
$$\frac{b}{3}= b$$

So a+b should equal to 446, so I came up with this:

$$\frac{x}{3} + \frac{b}{3}\geq 446$$

However, I am told that is incorrect and the explanation is this:

> Li Qiang counts at least *x* beats in the first movement. Therefore, *x* is less than or equal to what Li Qiang counts, which is less than or equal to the actual number of beats in the first movement, *a*

The correct answer is

$$\frac{x}{3} + \frac{b}{3}\leq 446$$

Why is "at least" in this case translated to $\leq$

Comment: Why is $\frac{b}{3} = b$?

Comment: A tricky question because the formulation "at least" and the meaningless number $x$ are confusing.

Comment: $\frac b3=b$ simplifies to $b=0$.

Comment: Oh yes I've just encountered that math question on Khan Academy too. Have just reported that to them though. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following three numbers :

- $x$ : An abstract number which has no meaning
- $c$ : The number of beats counted by Li Qiang
- $a$ : The actual number of beats

The text says that Li Qiang counted at least $x$ beats, so $c$ is at least $x$, therefore $c\ge x$. The actual number of beats is at least $c$, hence $a\ge c$, so finally, we have $a\ge c\ge x$

So, "at least" actually translates into $\ge$